# Is there a way to provide hint in template issues with Rich Editor in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I've set up issue templates on my gitlab project. like this

```
#  Bug Report

<!--- Provide a general summary of the issue here -->

##  Repro or Code Sample

<!-- Please provide steps to reproduce the issue and/or a code repository, gist, code snippet or sample files -->

##  Expected Behavior

<!--- Tell us what should happen -->
```

However when the Rich text editor is used all comments used to provide direction are deleted.

How to ensure that templates are selfexplanatory and easy to use (no need to rewrite everything) ?
Can I force simple text editor ?